# BASH: Bakup MySQL database and send via FTP to remote server

Tags: mysql, bash, curl, ftp

I trying to create BASH script for my API server where I do daily backup with cron. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

################################################################
##
##   MySQL Database Backup Script
##   Written By: Ivijan-Stefan Stipic
##   URL: https://infinitumform.com
##   Last Update: Jul 08, 2019
##
################################################################

export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

#################################################################

# Today date
TODAY=`date +"%d%b%Y"`

# Database
DATABASE_NAME='some_database_name'
MYSQL_HOST='localhost'
MYSQL_PORT='3306'
MYSQL_USER='some_username'
MYSQL_PASSWORD='pa55W0r6'

# FTP
FTP_HOST='https://someremote.host'
FTP_USER='ftp-username'
FTP_PASSWORD='ftp-p@55w0r6'
FTP_PATH='/backup'

# Backup location
DB_BACKUP_PATH='/root/backups'

# Filename setup
FILE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME} ## We can change this to some other name
FILE_NAME_PREFIX='' ## prefix in the file
FILE_NAME_SUFFIX='' ## suffix in the file

## Number of days to keep local backup copy
BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS=15   


# Full file path
FILE=${DB_BACKUP_PATH}/${TODAY}/${FILE_NAME_PREFIX}${FILE_NAME}${FILE_NAME_SUFFIX}-${TODAY}.sql.gz

#################################################################
if [ ! -z ${DATABASE_NAME} ]; then

    mkdir -p ${DB_BACKUP_PATH}/${TODAY}
    echo "Backup started for database - ${DATABASE_NAME}"

    mysqldump --host=${MYSQL_HOST} --port=${MYSQL_PORT} --databases ${DATABASE_NAME} --add-drop-database --triggers --routines --events --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} --user=${MYSQL_USER} --single-transaction | gzip > ${FILE}

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Database backup successfully completed"
    else
        echo "Error found during backup"
    fi

else
    echo "ERROR: Datbase not defined"
fi

##### Remove backups older than {BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS} days  #####
DBDELDATE=`date +"%d%b%Y" --date="${BACKUP_RETAIN_DAYS} days ago"`
if [ ! -z ${DB_BACKUP_PATH} ]; then
    cd ${DB_BACKUP_PATH}
    if [ ! -z ${DBDELDATE} ] && [ -d ${DBDELDATE} ]; then
        rm -rf ${DBDELDATE}
        echo  "Old backups cleaned up"
    fi
fi

#### Send backup via FTP ####
if [ ! -z ${FTP_USER} ]; then
    echo "Sending bakup files to ${FTP_HOST} via FTP"
    
    curl -T "${FILE}" -u ${FTP_USER}:${FTP_PASSWORD} ${FTP_HOST}${FTP_PATH}
    
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Files successfuly sent via FTP to remote bakup server"
    else
        echo "FTP error. Files was not sent properly."
    fi
fi
### End of script ####
```

In my office I have server where I keep backups and want to automate this script to send via FTP files from API server to my office server after backup is done.

I try to use cURL to send files but this fail.

```
...
#### Send backup via FTP ####
if [ ! -z ${FTP_USER} ]; then
    echo "Sending bakup files to ${FTP_HOST} via FTP"
    
    curl -T "${FILE}" -u ${FTP_USER}:${FTP_PASSWORD} ${FTP_HOST}${FTP_PATH}
    
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Files successfuly sent via FTP to remote bakup server"
    else
        echo "FTP error. Files was not sent properly."
    fi
fi
...
```

Is there some good and safe way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583481/how-to-create-cron-job-to-backup-mysql-and-ftp-backup-to-my-backup-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583481/how-to-create-cron-job-to-backup-mysql-and-ftp-backup-to-my-backup-server)

Comment: Hm... is not in the basic but this post you share have point. Maby `ncftpput` can be solution. Need to try but will love to use something already built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ncftpput`.

See my simple script about it, here: https://github.com/NabiKAZ/MySQL-Backup